# How to send data from main process to a specific sub-process in Python Multiprocess

Tags: python

I use multiprocessing.Process in Win10 Python to create multiple sub-processes to run a function in parallel, where each sub-process waits for the data from main-process the complete the whole task.
I know that using multiprocessing.Queue() can realize the communication between main process and sub-process. However, it doesn't specify which sub-process can get the data. It happens that sub-process-7 gets the data, which I intend to send to sub-process-2. Is there a way to specify sending data to a specific sub-process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to control which process should get a message use dedicated queues. Create a queue `queue2` and pass that to sub-process-2.